# Company Id returning 0 on API call

Tags: c#, api, automapper

Good evening all,

I am currently writing an API call to create a new Company on my database.  I have:

1. An AppUser class

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<AppUserCompanySetting> AppUserCompanySettings { get; set; }  = new List<AppUserCompanySetting>();
```

2. A CompanySetting class

```
public class CompanySetting
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
        public bool isArchived { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AppUserCompanySetting> AppUserCompanySettings { get; set; } = new List<AppUserCompanySetting>();
    }
```

3. A Join table for the two entities (AppUserCompanySetting.cs):

```
public class AppUserCompanySetting
    {
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }
        public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public int CompanySettingsId { get; set; }
        public virtual CompanySetting CompanySettings { get; set; }
    }
```

4. A DTO for the Company

```
public class CompanyDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
        public bool isArchived { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

5. An AutoMapper from CompanySetting to CompanyDto

```
CreateMap<CompanySetting, CompanyDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AppUserCompanySettings.Select(y => y.AppUserId).FirstOrDefault()));
```

6. My method for creating the company:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<CompanyDto>> AddNewCompany(CompanyDto companyDto)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == companyDto.UserId);

            var company = new CompanySetting
            {
                CompanyName = companyDto.CompanyName,
                CompanyRegistrationNumber = companyDto.CompanyRegistrationNumber,
                isActive = companyDto.isActive,
                isArchived = companyDto.isArchived,
            };

            user.AppUserCompanySettings.Add(new AppUserCompanySetting
            {
                AppUser = user,
                CompanySettings = company
            });

            _context.Users.Update(user);
            await _context.CompanySettings.AddAsync(company);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return new CompanyDto(){
                Id = companyDto.Id,
                CompanyName = companyDto.CompanyName,
                CompanyRegistrationNumber = companyDto.CompanyRegistrationNumber,
                isActive = companyDto.isActive,
                isArchived = companyDto.isArchived,
                UserId = companyDto.UserId
            };
        }
```

The API call almost works.  It creates the Company, updates the AppUserCompanySetting table correctly, but the return data shows:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "companyName": "My Test Company",
    "companyRegistrationNumber": "1985/123456/07",
    "isActive": true,
    "isArchived": false,
    "userId": 2
}
```

I am trying to figure out why the API call returns an ID of 0 and not the ID from the CompanySettings table (or CompanyDto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `companyDto` variable initially has `0` in it, since you are trying to create a new company. If that's the case, you never actually update thath field in your code, thus it remains the same.

You can return you result like this:

```
return new CompanyDto()
{
    Id = company.Id,
    CompanyName = company.CompanyName,
    CompanyRegistrationNumber = company.CompanyRegistrationNumber,
    isActive = company.isActive,
    isArchived = company.isArchived,
    UserId = companyDto.UserId
};
```

Basically, you have to use the actual `company` varialbe when you are doing the mapping back to the `dto`, since it will have the `Id` property set after calling the `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Thank you so much Timur.  My API is finally working 100%.  This was the most complex relationship I had to figure out for this system.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of assigning companydto.Id value to Id in return statement use company

```
return new CompanyDto(){
                Id = company.Id,
                CompanyName = company.CompanyName,
                CompanyRegistrationNumber = company.CompanyRegistrationNumber,
                isActive = company.isActive,
                isArchived = company.isArchived,
                UserId = company.UserId
            };
```

Comment: Thank you so much Amit.  Everything is working 100% now.  Now I can finally move forward